# how many $x$ satisfy $(\sin 2x + \sqrt 3 \cos 2x) ^2 - 5 = \cos (\pi/6 - 2x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> known $(\sin 2x + \sqrt 3 \cos 2x) ^2 - 5 = \cos (\pi/6 - 2x)$
>   -$3\pi/2 < x < 2\pi$

Just using $\sin (a\pm b) = \sin a . \cos b \pm \cos a . \sin b$

I get
$4(\sin (\pi/3 + 2x))^2 - 5 = \cos (\pi/6 - 2x)$ 
No $x$ satisfy it.

So the answer is 0? Any hints anyone?

Comment: there are $x$ which satisfy $4(\sin (\pi/3 + 2x))^2 - 5 = \cos (\pi/6 - 2x)$.

Answer (score 1):

In left side of the equation: $$(\sin 2x + \sqrt 3 \cos 2x) ^2=4\cdot\sin(2x+\pi/3)^2$$ and in the right side: $$\cos (\pi/6 - 2x)=\sin(2x+\pi/3)$$
So, the equation becomes: 
$$4\cdot\sin(2x+\pi/3)^2+\sin(2x+\pi/3)-5=0$$
Now let $t=\sin(2x+\pi/3)$ with $t\in[-1,1]$, so: $$4t^2+t-5=0$$
By the quadratic formula: $t=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+80}}{8}=10/8 (NO) \lor -1(YES)$

Now $$\sin(2x+\pi/3)=-1$$ and so: $x=7\pi/12+k\pi$ with $k\in Z$. So the solutions for $x \in [-3\pi/2,2\pi]$ are: $$x=-17\pi /12 \lor x=-5\pi/12 \lor x=7\pi/12 \lor x=19\pi/12$$

Comment: The right side moves to left shouldnt it changes its sign?

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$60^\circ +2x+30^\circ-2x=90^\circ$

$$\sin(60^\circ+2x)=\cos(?)$$

Now for real $x,$ $$-1\le\sin2x\le1$$

Finally $\cos y=-1\implies y=(2n+1)180^\circ$ where $n$ is an integer

Answer (score 0):

This might help (graph of all terms on a single side of an equation, so that the solution occurs when $y=0$).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin(2x)+(\sqrt3)\cos(2x)
=2 \left(\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)+\frac{(\sqrt3)}{2}\cos(2x)\right)
=2 \cos\left(2x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)
$$
The usual square equation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution at $x=7\pi/12$ and hence infinitely many solutions (the expression is periodic with period $\pi$).

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the equation as: $(1\cdot \sin(2x)+\sqrt{3}\cos(2x))^2 = 5+\cos(\frac{\pi}{6}-2x)$. Observe that by CS inequality applied to the LHS of the equation: $LHS \le (1^2+(\sqrt{3})^2)(\sin(2x)^2+\cos(2x)^2) = 4$ while the RHS of the equation: $RHS \ge 5 -1 = 4$. Thus $ = $ occurs when $ \dfrac{1}{\sin(2x)} = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{\cos(2x)}$ and $\cos(\frac{\pi}{6} - 2x) = - 1$ . This yields: $\cos(2x) = \sqrt{3}\sin(2x)$, and $\sqrt{3}\cos(2x) + \sin(2x) = -2 \implies \sin(2x) = -\frac{1}{2}, \cos(2x) = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\implies 2x = \frac{7\pi}{6}+2n\pi\implies x = \frac{7\pi}{12}+n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ .